Difference between solutions and roots
I used to think that 'solutions' refers to only the real solutions unless specified to be complex, and 'roots' refers to both the real and complex numbers that satisfy an equation; however, I am not able to find a reference for this. My teacher insists that they are the same; if so, then does the complete solution set of the inequality we have an inequality $${(x²+1)(x-2)/(x-3)≥0}$$ include $i$ and $-i$?

Isn't your x²+1 ugly? With Mathjax it is $x^2+1$.

When given an inequality in terms of $x,$ it is understood that $x$ is real, since complex numbers are unordered. 'Root' and 'solution' are synonyms and both can include/exclude complex numbers, depending on the context. For functions, although some people do say 'root', the most correct term is 'zero'. In neither case are you likely to hear an Australian mathematician say 'root'...

See Earliest Known Uses of Some of the Words of Mathematics for the complex historical evolution of both terms:
RADIX, ROOT, UNKNOWN, SQUARE ROOT. Late Latin writers used res for the unknown. This was translated as cosa in Italian, and the early Italian writers called algebra the Regola de la Cosa, whence the German Die Coss and the English cossike arte (Smith vol. 2, page 392).
Other Latin terms used in the Middle Ages for the uknown quantity and its square were radix, res, and census.
The term root was used by al-Khowarizmi; the word is rendered radix in Robert of Chester's Latin translation of the algebra of al-Khowarizmi.
Root (meaning "square root" or "cubic root" etc.) is found in English in 1557 in The whetstone of witte by Robert Recorde: "Thei onely haue rootes, whiche bee made by many multiplications of some one number by it self".
Unknown was used by Fermat. In "Novus Secundarum et Ulterioris Ordinis Radicum in Analyticis Usus," Fermat wrote (in translation): "There are certain problems which involve only one unknown..."
Unknown is found in English in 1676 in Glanvill: "The degree of Composition in the unknown Quantity of the Æquation".
Root (meaning "unknown") is found in English in 1728 in Chambers Cyclopedia: "The Root of an Equation, is the Value of the unknown Quantity in the Equation."
